# How to define multiple executables / Main modules with stack/hpack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I use [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) and a `package.yaml` file for [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) to compile my haskell project. It has three executables backed by one library.  As one would expect the executables are all defining a `Main` module:

```sh
$ head -n1 app/*
==> app/Foo.hs <==
module Main where

==> app/Bar.hs <==
module Main where

==> app/Baz.hs <==
module Main where
```

And I use this `package.yaml` which looks very similar (to me) to [the one](https://github.com/hspec/sensei/blob/master/package.yaml) linked from the [official docs for hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) (the third one).

```
name: myproject
dependencies:
  - base
library:
  source-dirs: src
executables:
  foo:
    main: Foo.hs
    source-dirs: app
    dependencies: myproject
  bar:
    main: Bar.hs
    source-dirs: app
    dependencies: myproject
  baz:
    main: Baz.hs
    source-dirs: app
    dependencies: myproject
```

But when I `stack build` I get the error, that the module name does not match
the file name:

```
Building all executables for `myproject' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
myproject-0.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library for myproject-0.0.0..
Building library for myproject-0.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Lib              ( src/Lib.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Lib.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_myproject  ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/autogen/Paths_myproject.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Paths_myproject.o )
Preprocessing executable 'bar' for myproject-0.0.0..
Building executable 'bar' for myproject-0.0.0..

/home/luc/test/app/Baz.hs:1:8: error:
    File name does not match module name:
    Saw: ‘Main’
    Expected: ‘Baz’
  |
1 | module Main where
  |        ^^^^


--  While building package myproject-0.0.0 using:
      /home/luc/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build lib:myproject exe:bar exe:baz exe:foo --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

The only difference between my setup and the example that I found was the capital letters of the files in `app/`. And indeed, if I change them to lower case (in the filesystem and the `package.yaml`) it all builds correctly.

But why is that and where is that documented?

Comment: In the discussion of Haskell modules, they mention that a module file Foo.hs must have a module named "Foo" in it. Haskell files that do not have an initial capital letter do not have that restriction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `app` should not be considered as a convention to be a folder of all final applications. In my projects I always split these to `foo/Main.hs` and `bar/Main.hs` for `foo` and `bar` targets. Hence
`package.yaml` should contain

```
executables:
  foo:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         foo
    dependencies:
    - myproject
  bar:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         bar
    dependencies:
    - myproject
```

And treat `myproject` just as a library for them

Comment: How does one build this after making these changes?  Running `stack build` results in a `<no location info>:` error

Comment: I was getting this error because the name of my main module was not `Main.hs`